# I need to find uplink and downlik frequency for ARFCN of an android device

Tags: android, network-programming, telephony

The following is a way to calculate the uplink and downlink frequencies for some of the bands, given the band, the ARFCN, and the offset.

GSM 900

Up = 890.0 + (ARFCN * .2) and
Down = Up + 45.0

**i cen get the GSM type, how can i get UP and DOWN frq, Which API will provide that, my terget is to get ARFCN**